# How to 'only' get the service 'status' in Windows? (alternative for `systemctl is-active service`)

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-scripting

I have been exploring on a windows alternative for following Linux command:

```
systemctl is-active firewalld
```

This command only gives us the strings **active** or **inactive** as output. So that it becomes helpful in developing various scripts.

I am so far unable to find such command for windows. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell:

```
$serviceName = "firewalld"
(get-service $serviceName).status
```

Will return Running/Stopped/Deactivated if a service with the name "firewalld" exists.